# Colorir uma região do gráfico

Tags: r

Gostaria de colorir apenas a região dentro do circulo, mas não estou conseguindo. O programa e a imagem são:

```
theta <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 200)
r = exp(1i*theta)

fx=function(r) {
 x = r-1
return (x) }

xi = fx(r)
plot(xi)
```

[image]

Comment: Vê se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794596/how-fill-part-of-a-circle-using-ggplot2

Comment: Ainda não está dando certo!

Comment: A pergunta diz respeito a colorir algum círculo com determinado centro e raio no R ou quer colorir a parte interna da figura gerada pela função fx?

Comment: Colorir apenas a parte interna da figura gerada pela função fx! Para uma outra função, meu interesse vai ser colorir a parte externa do circulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero que a melhor maneira de resolver este problema, dada [esta resposta ao meu comentário acima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153155/colorir-uma-regi%C3%A3o-do-gr%C3%A1fico#comment316307_153155), é fazer um polígono com os valores da função em vez de tentar fazer um círculo. Segue o código para isso:

```
theta <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 200)
r     <- exp(1i*theta)

fx <- function(r) {
    x = r-1
    return (x)
}

xi <- fx(r)

plot(xi)
polygon(Re(xi), Im(xi), col="cyan")
```

[image: Resultado do plot]

Note que simplesmente construí um polígono com as partes reais e imaginárias do resultado obtido pela função.